# Is the Black Soul Gem a Leveled Item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was looking information about the Black Soul Gems, and when I found out, that I can buy those things from a Wizard in Winterhold, I was wondering, do I need to be on a spesific Level before the gems appear in the Wizard's inventory.

Can they be bought on Level one (if you have the money), or do they appear only on higher Levels? And if they do appear on higher Levels, what's the minimum Level?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can buy Black Soul Gems from Falion in Morthal as soon as you get released into the wide world after the starting sequence. That is, if you have the cash.

Also, Enthir of the Mages College in Winterhold sells them, but I think you need to be a member before you can buy them off of him.

**edit**

Also, I seen from your comment below that you are level 18, I was able to buy off both parties with a level 9 save I had from yonks ago, so yeah, you should definitely be able to buy.

Also see the Elder Scrolls Skyrim Black Soul Gem [wiki page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Soul_Gem_%28Skyrim%29) for a list of the locations/creatures/characters where you are likely to find some.

Answer (score 1):

Through my experience in skyrim some merchants do change their wares as you level while it seems some just stick to base items.  I can't be sure if a merchant with the potential to sell black soul gems would sell them at lower levels or only to higher ones.  In order for enemies souls to actually go into a black soul gem though they must be around level 30-40 so if I had to guess I'd say that would be the level required to unlock them from a vendor if there is a level requirement at all.

Small spoiler alert:

> If you're worried about running out of grand souls and black soul gems you should google 
> the quest "The Black Star" as if you do the quest right, you can get a refillable black 
> soul gem.

Comment: As far as I know, only humanoid souls go into Black Soul Gems, and you can see bandits almost everywhere from the beginning of the game...but I guess that doesn't mean that if the first creatures of X (X is the size of the soul) soul appears to you the first time, the gems which fit on this same X soul appear at the same second in the Skyrim world. Cos if the gems appear at the same second, I could buy/find Black Soul Gems right away in the beginning (and I haven't yet found them [I am on Level 18]). However, I will look up he Quest you recommended.

Comment: This Quest is far beyond my strength. I cannot deal with it just yet. The fighting area is terrible, even for a Thief/Assassin.

Comment: I was looking info of Scrolls of Conjure Storm Atronach, when I figured out, how to make a Staff for calling them. It was the ultimate key for me to take down the bad guys on the Quest. It still took a lot of health potions, but I'm damn glad it's over and I got the Azura's Star.